# Java web start runs into CouldNotLoadArgumentException when pinned to task bar

Tags: java, windows-7, java-web-start

Wondering if others are running into this issue and there are known workarounds. Our UI is deployed via java web start. It works well except when users pin the icon to their task bar in Windows 7. We're using JRE 7u7.

`jaavws.exe` reports it can't find the cache, see below. Keep in mind this works perfectly when we launch the same icon from the desktop:

```
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: C:\Users\Chang_Lee\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\14\14bb61ce-3d47036e]
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[...]

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Chang_Lee\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\14\14bb61ce-3d47036e (The system cannot find the file specified)
                at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
                at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Check the [bug DB](http://bugs.sun.com/) & report back.

Answer (score 1):

URL for reported bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4774096 which only says they were unable to reproduce.

We had the same error occurring and user upgraded to Update 34 which didn't solve problem, but had application reinstalled and all works fine.

Dwain A Wuerfel